# HttpResponse with status code 0

Tags: httprequest, http, httppost

I am using an API to get some response.

When I check my `HttpResponse`. It is like this:

```
System.HttpResponse[Status=null, StatusCode=0]
```

In what case we get such a response?

Comment: Its not SF Specfic, probably it has do something with your webservice,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/what-does-it-mean-when-an-http-request-returns-status-code-0/14507670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the wrong `endPoint` provided in the `HttpRequest`.

After providing the correct URL the issue is resolved